# how to fix Dialogflow agent won't restore from a zip file

Tags: dialogflow-es, agent

I am trying to restore my agent from an existing backup zip file but when I select the file to upload it, the file is selected but won't be upload and the window remain as it is without any error as you can see in the screenshot.
I logged to my agent from a different computer and a different browser and still facing the same problem.

[image: and this is a screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Judging by this question, you may not be completely clear on how to best use this site. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [ask] a good question sections to see what questions are on and off topic, to see how this site works and to help you improve your future questions, which can help you get a better reception from site members and perhaps decent answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to type "RESTORE" into the text box, that activates the `Restore` button:) This is a safety mechanism, because restoring completely overwrites your existing agent.

Comment: Thank you so much,that helped me i just didn't notice that.